# Do you need an international drivers license in Taiwan?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, taiwan

According to [this website](https://tpcmv.thb.gov.tw/english/ServicesEng/LicenseEng/ManagementEng/ManagementEng01.htm) I don't need to have an international drivers license to drive in Taiwan as long as I'm not staying for more than 30 days. I'm only staying for 5 days.

I have a valid American drivers license with me, but did not bring my Taiwanese drivers license with me. Other websites contradict the Taiwan DMV by saying yes, I do need an international drivers license, including the AAA website.

Can I use a foreign driver's license if I'm staying in Taiwan less than 30 days?

Comment: Unfortunately your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @gnasher729 fixed

Answer (score 1):

Usually the requirement for an international license is there to make sure that the countries traffic police officers can look at your license if needed and decide that it is a valid license. Taiwan strongly encourages its students to learn English for various reasons, so it could be that US (or UK, Australian and other English language licenses) are allowed. I wouldn't suggest that *all* foreign licenses are allowed.

But your real problem will be to rent a car, so it would be a good idea to contact a rental car company. It is most likely that they are required by law to check that you have a license that allows you to drive the car, so if they say "yes" then it is most most likely Ok, and if they say "no" then it doesn't matter whether you are allowed to drive by law, because you don't have a car.

Answer (score 1):

Car rental agencies ask for the International Drivers Licence and so for practical purposes, you need one. They were quite strict about it and so I had one made just for the trip to Taiwan as most countries that officially ask for it, don't, at least in my experience. The easiest way for you to be sure is to read the agreement which you are required to accept before renting anyway. It was spelled out clearly and even asked me to supply a photocopy.

Answer (score -1):

There really is NO international driver's license, but what you need is a 'translation' of your valid driver's license and a photo that you can carry in the native language of the country you are visiting.  It may be labelled as an 'international license' but it dosn't have any legal authority.  You can obtain one for travel in any AAA office in the US.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. If we are talking about [International Driver Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit) that you can get from an AAA office in the US (and I did my research correctly), aren't that backed and subjected to international treaties? Or are you trying to point out the terminology is wrong?